# GCC compiler in CLION not found in PATH so cannot compile simple C++ program

Tags: c++, gcc, build, cmake, clion

When I try to compile a simple `main.cpp` consisting of:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

CLION tells me that:

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 9.3.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 9.3.0
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (project):
  The CMAKE_C_COMPILER:

    C:/cygwin64/bin/gcc.exe

  is not a full path and was not found in the PATH.

  Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
  variable "CC" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_C_COMPILER to the full path to
  the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.
```

I get the same block of messages for the `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:` referring to file `C:/cygwin64/bin/g++.exe`.

Both MAKE files exist in folder `C:\cygwin64\bin` and this path is referred to as an environment variable in Windows.

Looking at other questions posted concerning this kind of problem, I have checked the version settings of the compiler in CLION and I have:

[image]

And the MAKE settings are:

[image]

Can anyone please advise what I am missing here in order for the program to build and run?

In the `CMakeLists.txt` file I have also specified:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(HelloWorld1)

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER C:\cygwin64\bin)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER C:\cygwin64\bin)

add_executable(HelloWorld1 main.cpp)
```

But the result is still the same.

Comment: Have you installed cygwin on your machine? Also, if CLion detects cygwin, then you dont need to specify the `CMAKE_C_COMPILER` and `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` in the `CMakeLists.txt` file.

Comment: Yes. Cygwin resides in folder `C:\cygwin64\bin` and there is an environment variable for this as well.

Comment: Ok, then perhaps, can you try removing the 2 lines regarding `CMAKE_C_COMPILER` and `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` in the `CMakeLists.txt` file.

Comment: Doing this results in a message in CLION to say `Cannot find any MAKE profile.`

Comment: Within the CMake tab, did you manually fill in the other parameters, like the `-DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM`?

Comment: No. I left them to default settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's known [regression](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-19908) in CLion 2020.1 which will be fixed in the upcoming update.

As Workaround I removed custom compiler path from Toolchains setting page in CLion. It detects the same compiler and it works.